# in web driver is it possible to switch from one frame to another frame in the same webpage

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

in web driver is it possible to switch from one frame to another frame in the same webpage 
for example there are 2 frames in an webpage(frame1 and frame2)
i will switch to frame1 by using the code

```
driver.switchto().frame(id);
```

and i will perform operation inside the frame1

and again if i want to perform operation on frame2
do i need to switch back to window like

```
driver.switchto().defaultcontent();
```

and then do i need to go to frame2

or i can directly switch to frame2 from frame1

Comment: Why are you asking? Do you get an error when you switch directly from frame2 to frame1?

Comment: Do some Research by yourself ! Check to see if it works !

SO helps those who help themselves

Answer (score 4):

You will need to return to `defaultContent` before switching to frame-2 UNLESS frame-2 is located within frame-1.

```
<iframe id="1"></iframe>
<iframe id="2"></iframe>
```

The above would require:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("1");
//doSomething in frame 1
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame("2");
//doSomething in frame 2
```

But if the DOM looks like this:

```
<iframe id="1">
    <iframe id="2"></iframe>
</iframe>
```

Then you would use:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("1");
driver.switchTo().frame("2");
//doSomething in frame 2
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: why this line `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` is needed (*asked out of curiosity*)? But *+1* for producing a good example...indeed :)

Comment: After you switch to a frame, Webdriver can no longer 'see' the <body> as it now focuses solely on the iframe. So that you can access anything outside of the iframe, you need to switch back to the 'main' page - everything outside of that iframe. Hope that helps.

Comment: Very much helpful..If I could get your email id..probably ask some more help!! but would you allow ? :)

Comment: Thank u very much for the answer i got clarity on the concept.thanks